# Prevent 2 default functions from happening and trigger a third event at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Problem may sound pretty simple.....what i am trying to achieve is that, when form validation fails, i want to `show a custom alert box` and also `prevent form from submitting`

**Where i am stucked**

I am using  [Zebra_Dialog](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-dialog/#requirements)  for custom alert box...now, i know that `e.preventDefault()` stops the default function from triggering.....but this only stops one event
how shall i do following at same time :

- prevent default alert box from appearing
- prevent form from submitting
- show custom alert box

The plugin tutorial also mentions about preventing only the default alert box from happening

**HTML**

```
 <form id="searchform" class="input-append" method="post" action="search.php">
      <select class="city shadow" name="city" id="city">
         <option selected>Select your city</option>
         <option value="AAAAA">AAAAA</option>
      </select>

      <select class="location shadow" name="location">
         <option selected>Select your Location</option>
         <option value="Loc">Loc</option>
         <option value="Loc2">Loc2</option>
         <option value="Loc3">Loc3</option>
      </select>

      <select class="gender shadow" name="gender">
         <option selected>Select your gender</option>
         <option value="Male">Male</option>
         <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>

      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="search_room_for_me" id="search_room_for_me"> Search </button>

   </form>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
 $("#searchform").submit(function(e){

        var city = $(".city").val();
        var location = $(".location").val();
        var gender = $(".gender").val();

        if( city != "Select your city" )
        {
            if( location != "Select your Location")
            {
                if( gender != "Select your gender")
                {
                    //submit form
                }
                else
                {
                   e.preventDefault(); // here, default alert should stop
                   $.Zebra_Dialog('The link was clicked!');
                   alert("Invalid Gender Selected");
                   e.preventDefault(e); // prevent form submit
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Invalid Location Selected");
                e.preventDefault(e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Invalid City Selected");
            e.preventDefault(e);
        }
     });        




 </script>
```

Has anyone tried anything similar or is there any other method to achieve this!!??

Comment: What default alert box? Browsers dont show an alert when you submit a form

Comment: @Jamiec :did you bothered to go through the code i posted above before asking??????...but since you asked.......when `form validation fails`, i want to let user know that some value is not selected correctly in form, for this i need to `tigger` an `alert` box...like `alert("invalid value")`....by default it works....for rest, go through my complete question please  (not just title) :)

Comment: I went extensively though your code. However, the fact that you've decided to take quite a rude tone means I wont bother anymore with this question. I have also voted to close as it is unclear what you're asking - evidenced by the fact nobody else has answered this seemingly simple question. If you want to prevent your `alert` then don't put it there...simple!

Comment: @Jamiec : there was a smiley too in the end, should have noticed that too.....no probs still...thankx!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future visitor :

I was having the wrong order

```
e.preventDefault(); // here, default alert should stop
$.Zebra_Dialog('The link was clicked!');
alert("Invalid Gender Selected");
e.preventDefault(e); // prevent form submit
```

Instead, this worked

```
e.preventDefault(e);
$.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Gender :</strong>,Select your gender ,
Please select a proper gender to proceed ',
{'type':'error','title':'Select Gender'});
```

**Reason :**
There was a conflict in `e.preventDefault(e);`, only one `preventDefault(e)` is sufficient to stop all default features (dint knew this previously!!)